# How to get id of previous element by using mouseovered element's id which was taken from its class

Tags: jquery

I did this but it didn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
$('.current_element').mouseover(function() {
   var currentElementId = $(this).attr('id');
   var previousElementId = $('#' + currentElementId).prev('.previous_element').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
$('.current_element').mouseover(function() {
   var currentElementId = $(this).attr('id'); // if you don't need for any future
                                              // use then you can remove this line

   // $(this) refer to the hovered element
   var previousElementId = $(this).prev('.previous_element').attr('id');
});
```